# Why does clickhouse need so much memory for a simple query?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a simple query like:

```
SELECT w, x, y, z FROM my_table
WHERE microsecs >= 1234 AND microsecs <= 2345 AND a='foo' AND b='bar'
ORDER BY microsecs ASC
```

My primary key on the table is (a, b, microsecs).

The query should return about 295 million rows. I'm using clickhouse-driver to stream the data with [execute_iter](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#streaming-results).

Despite this, I need to set `max_memory_usage` to about 48GB for the query to succeed.

Why does clickhouse need so much memory for a simple query, and how can I reduce the required memory?

Answer (score 3):

I asked this question in the clickhouse_en telegram channel, and [I was pointed to](https://t.me/clickhouse_en/34133) the documentation on [optimizing read in-order](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/order-by/#optimize_read_in_order). I changed my ORDER BY from `ORDER BY microsecs` to `ORDER BY a, b, microsecs` and the memory required dropped dramatically.

Comment: yes this optimization is not implemented yet https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/7102
. Also you can spill intermediate data to the disk max_bytes_before_external_sort
max_bytes_before_external_group_by https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity/#settings-max_bytes_before_external_group_by